# use variable from while do loop bash

Tags: linux, bash, while-loop, session-variables

I have the while loop below that is using the variable pov. I need each line set to a variable that can be called in a connection string, but cant figure out how to create a loop to feed each line separately.

wanting `if [ ! -z $pov] then  .../shell to execute using $pov... fi` for each line in `seq_fy.txt`

What I am working with:

```
cat seq_fy.txt | while read pov; do
echo "pov$((n++))=$pov"
###wanting "if [ ! -z $pov] then <execute> fi" for each line in seq_fy.txt
done

$ ./while_loop_only
pov0=
pov1=SPT_SEQ_010,FY15
pov2=SPT_SEQ_010,FY16
pov3=SPT_SEQ_020,FY15
pov4=SPT_SEQ_020,FY16
pov5=SPT_SEQ_030,FY15
pov6=SPT_SEQ_030,FY16
pov7=SPT_SEQ_040,FY15
pov8=SPT_SEQ_040,FY16
pov9=SPT_SEQ_050,FY15
pov10=SPT_SEQ_050,FY16
```

Comment: What do you need to do here? Why are you fixated on sequentially named variables? What command do you *actually* need to run in that loop with the value of `$pov`?

Comment: its a call to OWS...I dont have to have to have it defined as POV, but I need the value of each line fed in as a variable to run business models. Right now, in a separate if statement, I do the following (after exporting pov1): export pov=${pov01//\"/}
$owsdirectory"/hpm_ws_client.sh" processCalcScriptOptions "$appName" "$pov" "$layers" "$stages" "" "$stages" "$stages" FALSE > "$appLogFolder""/""$step""_ProcessID.log"

Comment: I am new to scripting and having some difficulty explaining exactly what I am trying to do since the context doesn't make sense in most cases, but in general, I want to feed each line in as a parameter in a separate script until the end of the .txt file is reached

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I have been way over-analyzing this....
basically I don't need anything with POV or exporting variables at all, just simply put the command inside the while loop and fed in $line, and seems to work as expected

```
cat fiename.txt | while read line; do
$owsdirectory"/hpm_ws_client.sh" processCalcScriptOptions "$appName" "$line" "$layers" "$stages" "" "$stages" "$stages" FALSE > "$appLogFolder""/""$line""_ProcessID.log"
done
```

Comment: That's about right.  If you don't want to process empty arguments, add `if [ -n "$line" ]; then ...command...; fi` noting the spaces around the `[` command name and its matching `]` last argument, and the quotes around the variable.  Get used to quoting variables; it is normally correct.  In your code, if would be better to write either `"$owsdirectory"/hpm_ws_client.sh` or `"$owsdirectory/hpm_ws_client.sh"`, enclosing the variable in double quotes once more.  The log file name can be simplified from `"$appLogFolder""/""$line""_ProcessID.log"` to `"$appLogFolder/${line}_ProcessID.log"`.